# Error: Non invocable "dictationgrammar' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I am following a tutorial on speech recognition from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caYyjxujZuU&feature=youtu.be

I am using the following code inside my form's button method, but it won't compile and the compiler is giving me the following error message.

> non invocable "dictationgrammar' cannot be used like a method

How can I fix my code to get rid of this error?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    private static SpeechRecognitionEngine engine;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        engine.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(DictationGrammar()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says, you can't `invoke` something that isn't a method. In this line `Grammar(DictationGrammar()` you are using `DictationGrammar` like it is a function.  I am guessing you meant `Grammar(new DictationGrammar())`

Comment: You need to watch the rest of the video - it doesn't stay like that for long. See around 10:30.